# Accessing Leaf Certificate Private Key

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I created a root CA with a private key from the Vault. I then created an internal certificate using the root CA. I want to use the certificate private key to encrypt data for mTLS in my application. How do I access the private key?

According to [the FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/sa/security/cloud-security/ssl-tls-certificates/faq/)  I should be able to download it.

I tried using the CLI but it only gives me the certificate and the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it :)

use `--bundle-type CERTIFICATE_CONTENT_WITH_PRIVATE_KEY`

Full command:

```bash
oci certificates certificate-bundle get --certificate-id <cert_ocid> --bundle-type CERTIFICATE_CONTENT_WITH_PRIVATE_KEY
```